# AUTH_DISABLED warning when trying to MERGE inside apoc.when()

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Neo4j 3.4. I am trying to insert a new node `(a)` into a time line between `(t)` and `(n)`. Each time node has a timestamp. My problem is that node `(t)` sometimes has the same timestamp as my new node `(a)`. I am using `apoc.when` to determine if it is not the same in order to make the insert, else do nothing.

```
MATCH (t:time)-[r:next*1]->(n:time) WHERE n.time > 1528601855959 AND t.time <= 1528601855959 
WITH n,t,r
CALL apoc.when(
    (t.time <> 1528601855959),
    'UNWIND r as rd DELETE rd WITH t,n MERGE (t)-[:next]->(a:time{time:1528601855959, src:"time"})-[:next]->(n)','', {t:t, r:r, n:n}) YIELD value as rr
RETURN t,n
```

I have two problems I can't crack:
First is the error message:

> Neo.ClientError.Security.Forbidden: Write operations are not allowed
>   for AUTH_DISABLED with FULL restricted to READ.

I've tried to find this setting in the config files with no luck. Is there something wrong with the code or can i just change a config setting?

The second problem is basic and may work after the AUTH issue is fixed - how can I return `(a)` when/if it's created? - i.e. `RETURN a,t,n`.

https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_when_procedures

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apoc.when` procedure executes only in read mode. To write, use the `apoc.do.when` procedure, and to get the added node use `RETURN`:

```
MATCH (t:time)-[r:next*1]->(n:time) WHERE n.time > 1528601855959 AND t.time <= 1528601855959 
WITH n, t, r
CALL apoc.do.when(
  t.time <> 1528601855959,
  '  UNWIND r as rd DELETE rd WITH t,n 
     MERGE (t)-[:next]->(a:time {time: 1528601855959, src: "time"})-[:next]->(n) RETURN a',
  '', {t: t, r: r, n: n}) YIELD value AS rr
RETURN t, n, rr.a AS a
```